# Unable to use variable in react js functional component, I am using JSX extension file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native

I am using React JS in Laravel, I created one functional component with JSX extension file and trying to use simple variable but unable to use that in HTML tag.

```js
import React from 'react';

//functional component
const HeaderComp = () => {
    const MIX_APP_URL = process.env.MIX_APP_URL;
    console.log(MIX_APP_URL);//here working fine
    return (
        <header>
            {/*Here not working*/}
            <img src="{MIX_APP_URL}" className="img img-fluid" />
        </header>
   );
};
```

Comment: Try without the quotes: `src={MIX_APP_URL}`.

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx

Comment: okay checking..

Comment: Yes worked fine thanks @Andy